# How to access the arguments of a function that is an argument in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am having a hard time wrapping my head around this idea. Suppose I have the following

```
var func1 = function(func2){
        return func2
    }

var addTwo = function(x) {return x + 2};
var two = func1(addTwo(2))

console.log(two) // returns 4
```

If I wanted to add code to `func1` that refers to the argument(s) in `addTwo` or any other function that I choose as an argument how would I do this? I want access to the arguments of the functional argument in func1. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Your "func1" will return whatever it's passed, whether it's a function or the string "hello world". Your "addTwo" function will return `4` when you call it, so that's what "func1" returns.

Comment: What if I wanted to console.log func2's arguments by calling func1 with only func2 as an argument?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. `func2` doesn't have arguments until you call it. If you just pass `func2` as an argument, it hasn't been called, so there are no arguments to log.

Answer (score 0):

You could write it like this.

```
var func1 = function(val, func2){
        return func2(val);
    }

var addTwo = function(x) {return x + 2};
var two = func1(2, addTwo);

console.log(two); // returns 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be what you want:

```js
function log_and_call(func, args) {
  args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1); // Get arguments except first
  console.log(args);
  return func.apply(this, args);
}
var addTwo = function(x) {return x + 2; };
log_and_call(addTwo, 2); // Logs [2] and returns 4
var multiply = function(x, y) { return x * y; }
log_and_call(multiply, 3, 4); // Logs [3, 4] and returns 12
```

`arguments` is a special variable that contains a list of all the arguments passed to the current function. This uses `slice` to skip over the `func` argument and just get the rest.

You can't call it as `log_and_call(addTwo(2))` because when you write `addTwo(2)`, that calls the function and returns its value, and that value is passed to `log_and_call`. There's no way for `log_and_call` to intercede in that call or see the structure of it, it just gets the result.